# copy and paste in vista turns to shortcut

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I use Vista but when I copy and paste a file they all become a shortcut. I don't think there is any Trojan or Virus. Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Has it always done this?  Have you tried a reboot?  Does it do it in Safe Mode? How after a system restore?  What have you tried already?

Comment: How do you perform the copy and paste?

Comment: I right click, copy and then paste when I am in a different folder. It has been this way for about 3 months now... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you should rule out malware:

- Check if the shortcuts that get created actually point to the original files and **only** the original files.

  Lately, it's common practice for malware to create apparently valid shortcuts that actually open the desired program/file/folder, but they start a malicious program first. If these shortcuts get created on removable media, you could spread the infection to other computers.
- Apart from the previous check, you should [start the computer in safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/start-your-computer-in-safe-mode) (as @techie007 already suggested) and see if the problem persists.
- If there's malware interfering with your copy&paste, it might have modified your `shell32.dll`.

  Uploading it to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) couldn't hurt.

If it's not malware, you'll have to start troubleshooting:

- If might be interesting to know what *eaxctly* is affected.

  Try if the same behavior occurs using the kayboard shortcuts for copying (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and pasting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>).

  Also, your context menu should have different entries for **Paste** and **Paste shortcut**:

  [image: screenshot]

  Does it?
- Try [Windows Update](http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com).
- Try re-registering your `shell32.dll`:

  1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
  2. Execute `regsvr32 /i shell32.dll`.
  3. Restart the computer.
- If your `shell32.dll` has been modified, you could attempt to get a clean one from your installation media, the `ServicePackFiles` folder (if there is one) or another computer with Windows Vista. **Do not download it!**

  You'd have to use a tool like [Replacer](http://www3.telus.net/_/replacer/) or boot your computer from a optical disk, a flash drive or another partition to do this. Also, make sure you make a backup copy of your `shell32.dll` and create a system restore point in case anything goes wrong. To do this:

  1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
  2. Click `System Protection`.
  3. Click `Create`.

  Even with a restore point, **you do this at your own risk**.
- If everything else fails, try performing a [repair install](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/88236-repair-install-vista.html).